# Which groups can be generated by a single conjugacy class?

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, conjugacy-classes

How can we characterize the finite groups generated by a subset of a single conjugacy class?

[This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3411156/what-sort-of-groups-are-generated-by-a-single-conjugacy-class) asks for well-known families of finitely generated groups generated by a single conjugacy class. I am interested in whether there is a classification of all such groups.

If a completely general classification isn't known, what are some ways that we can classify such groups subject to certain restrictions?
A simple example of such a statement would be that any non-identity conjugacy class generates a finite group $G$ if and only if $G$ is simple.

Comment: I would guess almost any group which is generated by a single conjugacy class is generated by at least one proper subset of the conjugacy class, consisting of all elements of the conjugacy class but one. So there's not likely to be a reasonable classification.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Do you mean that it's unlikely that there is a reasonable classification of the groups that are generated by a single conjugacy class, or that it's unlikely there is a reasonable classification of the particular generating sets contained within a conjugacy class?

Comment: I think Will is saying the focus of your present question on "subsets" is odd (compared to the one you link to, which just asks about groups generated by one conjugacy class).

Comment: That is fair. I've edited the question.

Comment: Groups generated by a single conjugacy class are exactly those whose abelianization $G/[G,G]$ is cyclic; more generally, the minimal number of conjugacy classes needed to generate $G$ is the rank of the abelianization. See Lemma 3.1 here: https://arxiv.org/pdf/2106.09126.pdf